# How to reference @types/module in typescript?

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

After I install module like `@types/express` via `npm`, how do I reference it in typescript?

I have try followings :

1. `/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts" />` still give me `can not find module 'express'` error
2. `import * as express from '@types/express';` can pass the typescript compilation, but after compile will be `require('@types/express')` which should be `require('express')` instead.

Comment: why not `import * as express from 'express'` ?

Comment: I have try that too,  give me `can not find module 'express'`, I think is because express modules does not contain typings field in package.json.

Comment: what version of tsc are you using? this is supposed to be a feature of 2.0.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.10, maybe this is the root cause, let me try it later, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I found the newest version is 1.8 :(

Comment: 2.0 is in beta according to their github page. try installing typescript@next :)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases the releases page

Comment: @toskv you should write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a TypeScript 2.0+ plus. It will not work with versions earlier than that.

As of now 2.0 is still in beta but there is a release candidate available as the **typescript@rc** version. To install i run:

```
npm install -g typescript@rc
```

The nightly build is also available as **typescript@next**:

```
npm install -g typescript@next
```

Comment: There is now a release candidate that includes numerous bug fixes: `npm install -g typescript@rc`

Comment: there's even a newer one @beta I think, from their blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/

Comment: According to `npm info typescript`, the available tags and versions are: `'dist-tags': { latest: '1.8.10', next: '2.1.0-dev.20160921', beta: '2.0.0', rc: '2.0.2' }`. The `rc` is newer than the `beta`, but there is also `next` - the nightly build. And the blog entry for the `rc` is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/08/30/announcing-typescript-2-0-rc/).